# How can same name data from same table added its quantity and insert into another table?

Tags: php

In my application has a input table where we can insert same product date wise with product quantity and finally same name product quantity addition and insert into another table called final table.

input table :

```
 Date     |  Name   | qty
22-05-209  Product1  20
23-05-209  Product2  10
25-05-209  Product1  30
```

final table :

```
 Name     |   qty
 Product1     50
 Product2     10
```

Using this code..but it doesnt work. its only insert single data , qty doesnt addition

```
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE total SET qty = (SELECT qty FROM input WHERE total.name = input.name)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update 'total' table with SUM of values you want like following :
Try this:

```
UPDATE total t2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT name, SUM(qty) as qty_total
  FROM input
  GROUP BY name
) t1 ON t2.name = t1.name
SET t2.qty = t1.qty_total
```

Comment: there you use t2 for total table and t1 for ?

Comment: I changed the code to use INNER JOIN - t2 is alias for 'total' table and t1 for 'input' table you referred

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav Happy to help :)